# About LoopBack query

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

I found loopback is a cool framework. While I am learning it, I found out something wired.

When I make queries, for example, using updateAll. If the parameter is undefined, the query will update all data.

```
Employee.updateAll(
    {
        username: undefined
    },
    {
        address: "ABC"
    }, function(err, results) { 
});
```

Why it will update all the data when the value is undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am core developer of the LoopBack framework.*

LoopBack is designed to treat `undefined` the same way as if the property was not defined at all. This mimics the behavior of JSON format, where properties with `undefined` values are simply omitted from the string output.

As a result, your filter `{username: undefined}` is interpreted as an empty filter `{}`, which is interpreted as "no conditions" and therefore matches all records (model instances).

If you are using an SQL database to store your data, then using `null` instead `undefined` should work well for you.

Detecting empty (`undefined`) properties in other (NoSQL) databases is tricky, I don't have any one-size-fits-all answer for that.

Comment: in the Model definition JSON file page, there is model property called required. When I run the create, it will return validation error if the required set to true. However, when I run the updateAll, it will not return validation error if the required set to true. So, the required only validates create but not the updateAll or others?

Comment: @jdc9090 this is not how StackOverflow works! If you have another question, then please post (ask) a new question :)